# Copy cells between workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

Could someone please help me with some VBA code.

I am trying to copy 2 ranges of cells between workbooks (both workbooks should be created beforehand as i don't want the code to create a new workbook on the fly).

Firstly I need to copy these ranges-
From 'Sheet 3' of booka.xls,  Range: Cell H5 to the last row in column H with data
  copy this to 'Sheet 1' of bookb.xls, starting in Cell B2 for as many cells down in the B column

Secondly I need to copy these ranges-
From 'Sheet 3' of booka.xls,  Range: Cell K5 to the last row in column K with data
  copy this to 'Sheet 1' of bookb.xls, starting in Cell D2 for as many cells down in the D column

Here is what I have so far:

```
 Sub CopyDataBetweenBooks()

Dim iRow        As Long
    Dim wksFr       As Worksheet
    Dim wksTo       As Worksheet

    wksFr = "C:\booka.xls"
    wksTo = "C:\bookb.xls"

    Set wksFrom = Workbooks(wksFr).Worksheets("Sheet 3")
    Set wksTo = Workbooks(wksTo).Worksheets("Sheet 1")

    With wksFrom
        For iRow = 1 To 100
            .Range(.Cells(iRow, 8), .Cells(iRow, 9)).Copy wksTo.Cells(iRow, 8)
        Next iRow
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Are there blanks in any of the columns?

Comment: yes, the cell values will vary but it is expected there will be some blanks

Comment: Look up the Workbooks.Open function, as I don't believe you can open the workbooks like you are doing.  If there will be blanks interspersed look up the SpecialCells property of a range.  Take another crack at it and I'll help you with what I have.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how to do one of the columns:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopyCells()
    Dim wkbkorigin As Workbook
    Dim wkbkdestination As Workbook
    Dim originsheet As Worksheet
    Dim destsheet As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Integer
    Set wkbkorigin = Workbooks.Open("booka.xlsm")
    Set wkbkdestination = Workbooks.Open("bookb.xlsm")
    Set originsheet = wkbkorigin.Worksheets("Sheet3")
    Set destsheet = wkbkdestination.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lastrow = originsheet.Range("H5").End(xlDown).Row
    originsheet.Range("H5:H" & lastrow).Copy  'I corrected the ranges, as I had the src
    destsheet.Range("B2:B" & (2 + lastrow)).PasteSpecial 'and destination ranges reversed
End Sub
```

As you have stated in the comments, this code above will not work for ranges with spaces, so substitute in the code below for the `lastrow` line:

```
lastrow = originsheet.range("H65536").End(xlUp).Row
```

Now ideally, you could make this into a subroutine that took in an origin workbook name, worksheet name/number, and range, as well as a destination workbook name, worksheet name/number, and range.  Then you wouldn't have to repeat some of the code.

Comment: good start but it doesn't copy anything after the first blank cell

Comment: @trunks Yes, that's why I was indicating that you'd need the `SpecialCells` property of the `Range`.  If you want to maintain the blanks, you'll have to start your range at 65536 (the last cell) and work your way up to the last filled spot using xlUp.  I've given you a nudge, but you'll have to do some of the footwork.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the reference to `wksFrom` and `wksTo`, here is what the code should be

```
wksFrom.Range(wksFrom.Range("H5"), wksFrom.Range("H5").End(xlDown)).Copy wksTo.Range("B2")
wksFrom.Range(wksFrom.Range("K5"), wksFrom.Range("K5").End(xlDown)).Copy wksTo.Range("D2")
```

Comment: Will stop at first blank cell as well, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @Lopsided: Yes. However, OP's code doesnt require the need to check for blanks. The assumption is that the column is filled with values and there aren't any blanks between the cells.

Comment: @shahkalpesh doesn't he specifically say in a comment to his answer that the values will differ but there are expected to be some blanks? Maybe I am misunderstanding him.

Comment: @Lopsided: Yes, he did. I didn't read it till you pointed it out. Neither his code, nor the other upvoted answer has that point considered. It would've been better if the comments by OP were consolidated in the question to have the requirements in detail than in comments, when asked of by. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use special cells like Jonsca has suggested. However, I usually just loop through the cells. I find it gives me more control over what exactly I am copying. There is a very small effect on performance. However, I feel that in the office place, making sure the data is accurate and complete is the priority. I wrote a response to a question similar to this one that can be found here:

- **[StackOverflow - Copying Cells in VBA for Beginners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495769/excel-macro-paste-only-non-empty-cells-from-one-sheet-to-another/14496277#14496277)**

There is also a small demonstration by iDevelop on how to use special cells for the same purpose. I think that it will help you. Good luck!

### Update

In response to...

> good start but it doesn't copy anything after the first blank cell – trunks Jun 9 '11 at 5:08

I just wanted to add that the tutorial in the link above will address the issue brought up in your comment. Instead of using the `.End(xlDown)` method, loop through the cells until you reach the last row, which you retrieve using `.UsedRange.Rows.Count`.