# How do I use Excel VBA to copy specific cells from two workbooks and combine them into one?

Tags: vba, excel

I have two excel workbooks that I am trying to read from. I need to read from a column in the first one, and compare that field to a field in the second workbook. If there is a match, I want to copy the original row to a new excel workbook, and append the name with a piece of another column. Furthermore, if another column in that row is filled, I need to duplicate the original row again into the new workbook, and append that name. That will happen up to 20 times per row, but not always.

Basically, I need to do something like this:

```
Workbook A:

Name         OtherData1     OtherData2
--------     ----------     ----------
Railroad     Data           Data
MailRoute    Data           Data
BoatPath     Data           Data

Workbook B:

Name          rtuTopic[1]   rtuTopic[2]   [.....]   rtuTopic[20]
--------      --------      --------                --------
Railroad      Route_01      Route_05                Route_21
MailRoute     Route_12      NULL                    NULL
BoatPath      Route_01      Route_15                NULL

Workbook C (the result I want)

Name            OtherData1     OtherData2     rtuTopic
--------        ----------     ----------     --------
Railroad_01     Data           Data           Route_01
Railroad_05     Data           Data           Route_05
...........
Railroad_21     Data           Data           Route_21
MailRoute_12    Data           Data           Route_12
BoatPath_01     Data           Data           Route_01
BoatPath_15     Data           Data           Route_15
```

The columns I need to append are not conveniently next to one another. They are separated by 5 or 6 other columns, give or take, and I don't know where to get started. I searched around and saw how to copy entire sheets from one workbook to another, but I didn't see how to really specifically dig down and duplicate a row the way I need to.

Comment: possible duplicate of [VBA excel - copy cells between workbooks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287405/vba-excel-copy-cells-between-workbooks)

Answer (score 0):

It seems more like you are asking for a solution to be written for you rather than asking a specific question but here are some pointers to get you going:

Assuming the other workbooks are already open you can refer to the otherbooks using the workbooks list i.e.

```
Dim workBookA As Workbook
Dim workBookB As Workbook
Dim workBookC As Workbook

Set workBookA = Workbooks("Workbook A")
Set workBookB = Workbooks("Workbook B")
Set workBookC = Workbooks("Workbook C")
```

The sheets in those workbooks can be referenced using the name of the sheet i.e. if you want a sheet called "Main" on Workbook A then you could use:

```
workBookA.Sheets("Main").Activate
```

Copying one column from the sheet to one call "Report" on Workbook C could be done like:

```
workBookA.Sheets("Main").Range("a1", workBookA.Sheets("Main").Range("a1").End(xlDown)).Copy
workBookC.Sheets("Report").Range("a1").PasteSpecial
```

or if this is easier to follow

```
workBookA.Sheets("Main").Activate
Range("a1", Range("a1").End(xlDown)).Copy
workBookC.Sheets("Report").Activate
Range("a1").PasteSpecial
```

Good luck

Comment: I didn't mean for it to sound like I was asking for the work to be done for me. Thanks for the input though. I will have to get back to this a bit later though, my tasks have been swapped for the next day or two. More than anything, I appreciate the starting point. :)