# How can I copy data(include format, but except formula) from one excel to other excel?

Tags: excel

I want to copy data from one excel to other excel.
I first used CTRL + C / CTRL + V and copied data, format and formula all.
But I only need data and format. Any suggestion?

Comment: google your problem..

Comment: I answered something similar a while ago, maybe it's helpful to you. [VBA copy cells value and format](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25461657/1175077)

Comment: possible duplicate of [VBA excel - copy cells between workbooks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287405/vba-excel-copy-cells-between-workbooks)

Comment: Also, it's not clear if you want to copy between sheets or workbooks.

Comment: @gpinkas i don't want to use macro, thx.

Comment: @jpw yes, copy data with format and paste to other workbooks, but without formula - for instance, cell A value is 1 and cell B value is 2, cell C get value using formula 'Cell A + Cell B'. I want paste 3 not the formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution in support of office.

pls see: https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Copy-cell-values-not-formulas-12687b4d-c79f-4137-b0cc-947c229c55b9